# Multiline button html php

Tags: php, html, css

I am making a list button with h5 text, all there button have there same width, but when there text is longer then there button width expand. I need there text to be more lines, and not make the button width expand.

```
for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++)
{
   echo "<button><h5>".$description."</h5></button>";
}
```

Comment: add a style with `word-wrap: break-word;`

Comment: Set a width to <button style="width:150px">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Carl Jan et @Roy said in the comments, add `word-wrap` property combined with a `width` on the button :

```css
button { width: 100px; }
button h5 { word-wrap: break-word; }
```

```html
<button><h5>Multiline button very long text</h5></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this after cross browser testing and with multiple buttons with same width

```css
button{
  
  display: inline-block;
  max-width : 100px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
        white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;
        white-space: -pre-wrap;
        white-space: -o-pre-wrap;
        word-wrap: break-word;
}
h1{display:block;
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<button>
<h1>
testtesttesttest
</h1>
</button>
<button>
<h1>
test1
</h1>
</button>
<button>
<h1>
test2
</h1>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based from your code:

```
for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++)
{
   echo '<button style="word-wrap:break-word;"><h5>'.$description.'</h5></button>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have set a fixed width for each button, I would also set a min-height (assuming your descriptions have a character limit), then use:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

on the buttons, this will force the description text to wrap round onto several lines.